# .exe not working on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: c#, windows, server, exe, windows-server-2008

I've been having some problems for the last 5 days with and .exe that I've made in Visual Studio Code (last version) on my PC with Windows 10. The issue is that the file isn't working in the server where I put it which has a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise version. I've tried doing it using Python, VB and C# and none of the cases work.
I leave the code in C# next:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace EmailSender
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Datos de autenticación del correo electrónico
            string smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com";
            int smtpPort = 587;
            string smtpUsername = "example@outlook.com";
            string smtpPassword = "example";

            string rutaCarpeta = "C:/Example";

            string[] archivosExcel = Directory.GetFiles(rutaCarpeta, "*.xls")
                .OrderByDescending(f => new FileInfo(f).CreationTime)
                .Take(4)
                .ToArray();

            MailMessage correo = new MailMessage();
            correo.From = new MailAddress("example@outlook.com");
            correo.Subject = "Example subject";
            correo.To.Add("example@gmail.com");
            correo.To.Add("example2@gmail.com");
            correo.Body = "Example body.";

            foreach (string archivo in archivosExcel)
            {
                correo.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(archivo));
            }

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpServer, smtpPort);
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);

            smtpClient.Send(correo);

            Console.WriteLine("Example writeline.");
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of the .exe is to take 4 Excel files from a default folder and send them to some default emails.
I've tried different languages, some compatibility configurations, different e-mail providers...

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What happens when you start it? Did you check the Windows Event Logs?

Comment: 2008 R2 needs extra work to make it use TLS 1.2, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392 have you done the update and modified the Registry? In any case it's way out of date, you should upgrade pronto.

Comment: Sending email over SSL(587) fails silently without throwing an exception even though yoi have followed the documentation to the last word.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I was able to solve it by modifying the security settings of Outlook 2007 (it wouldn't let me send emails automatically) and after several tests, it worked perfectly.

Comment: I have no idea how Outlook was relevant to this question, you dont' mention it anywhere